# How to write data in each row in csv file with column header in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write data in each row in csv file without overwriting but with a header column.  With this code I am able to write the data in every row of the file but also it write the header. I want that the header is also on the top of the column and then in each raw just to write the data. This the code Im using

```
import csv
c =csv.writer(open("C:/Config/Output/box.csv","ab"), lineterminator='\n')
c.writerow(['ColA','ColB'])
c.writerow([dfl_origin[0],dfl_origin[1]])
```

dfl_origin[0] and dfl_origin[1] are varaibles.

Ok this is the more of the code

```
def calculate_doorframe_parameters(subfeature_dict):
    global dfl_hor_thr , dfl_ver_thr
    global dfl_origin
    dfl_points_dict = {}

    for subfeature in subfeature_dict:
        if ("doorframelines" in subfeature):
            dfl_points_dict[subfeature] = subfeature_dict[subfeature]

    if len(dfl_points_dict) == 2: #Invalid Case for algorithm (Can be removed after confirmation)
        dfl_hor_thr =  abs(dfl_points_dict['doorframelines1'][0] - dfl_points_dict['doorframelines2'][0])

    if len(dfl_points_dict) == 6:
        dfl_hor_thr = abs(dfl_points_dict['doorframelines2'][0] - dfl_points_dict['doorframelines5'][0])
        dfl_ver_thr =  abs(dfl_points_dict['doorframelines6'][1] - dfl_points_dict['doorframelines4'][1])

        #Find Origin of DoorFrame
        dfl_origin_X = min([dfl_points_dict['doorframelines2'][0], dfl_points_dict['doorframelines5'][0],dfl_points_dict['doorframelines1'][0] , dfl_points_dict['doorframelines3'][0]])
        dfl_origin_Y = min([dfl_points_dict['doorframelines2'][1], dfl_points_dict['doorframelines5'][1],dfl_points_dict['doorframelines1'][1] , dfl_points_dict['doorframelines3'][1]])
        dfl_origin= [dfl_origin_X,dfl_origin_Y]
        import csv
        c =csv.writer(open("C:/Config/Output/box2.csv","ab"), lineterminator='\n')
        c.writerow(['ColA ColB'])
        c.writerow([dfl_origin[0],dfl_origin[1]])
```

And this is the result

```
ColA, ColB
1033  87.0
ColA  ColB
987   65.0
```

The expected results should be

```
    ColA, ColB
    1033  87.0
    987   65.0
```

Any help?

Comment: What is `dfl_origin`? Please show a little more of your code.

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Why is your current code not working? What isn't it doing that it should be?

Comment: And the expected result?

Comment: the expected result should be only in the first row the column header and then in each row to write the data. Understand?

Comment: Well, if it's that simple, why not just move the `c.writerow(['ColA ColB'])` outside the loop, hm?

Comment: Which loop? The loop in csv file? sorry Im not fluent in python

Comment: Move it above `for subfeature in subfeature_dict:`, understand? ;)

Comment: If move it there I got this error: line 294, in calculate_doorframe_parameters
    c.writerow(['ColA ColB'])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment

Comment: Oh wow I just noticed. Please, open your file outside the loop. Move `import csv; c = csv.writer(open("C:/Config/Output/box2.csv","ab"), lineterminator='\n')` above the loop as well.

Comment: No. Its the same. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
with open('names.csv', 'a') as csvfile:

    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

'a' stands for 'append' solves overwriting issues,

For more:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html